# How do I run pandas on replit

Tags: pandas

I have a python code for a discord bot. It is working locally but when I try to run it on replit.com I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/runner/Animanji/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/home/runner/Animanji/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import (
  File "/home/runner/Animanji/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (
  File "/home/runner/Animanji/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 70, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/home/runner/Animanji/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 157, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame
  File "/home/runner/Animanji/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 152, in <module>
    from pandas.core.window import (
  File "/home/runner/Animanji/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/window/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.window.ewm import (  # noqa:F401
  File "/home/runner/Animanji/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/window/ewm.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations
ImportError: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already installed the packages but didn't work, but it pandas does work on the bash window when I run python3 there.

Comment: Have you installed packages in the replit workspace or in your local space?

Comment: in the replit workspace

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any solution other than forking another repl and putting my files there.
here is the repl if anyone is interested: https://replit.com/@HourKesh/AppropriateKnobbyInstruction#poetry.lock .

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the replit shell and type pip3 install pandas.